# Facebook Graph API v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am trying to get my friend name and ids with Graph API v2.0, but data returns empty:

```js
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

When I was using v1.0, everything was OK with the following request:

```c
FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              NSDictionary* result,
                                              NSError *error) {
    NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSLog(@"Found: %i friends", friends.count);
    for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {
        NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@ with id %@", friend.name, friend.id);
    }
}];
```

But now I cannot get friends!

Comment: a possible overcome to this problem

http://stackoverflow.com/a/25584013/2529087

Answer (score 634, accepted):

In v2.0 of the Graph API, calling `/me/friends` returns the person's friends who also use the app.

In addition, in v2.0, you must request the `user_friends` permission from each user. `user_friends` is no longer included by default in every login. Each user must grant the `user_friends` permission in order to appear in the response to `/me/friends`. See [the Facebook upgrade guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids) for more detailed information, or review the summary below.

If you want to access a list of non-app-using friends, there are two options:

1. **[If you want to let your people tag their friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/taggable_friends)** in stories that they publish to Facebook using your App, you can use the `/me/taggable_friends` API. [Use of this endpoint requires review by Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/taggable_friends) and should only be used for the case where you're rendering a list of friends in order to let the user tag them in a post.
2. **[If your App is a Game AND your Game supports Facebook Canvas](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/invitable_friends)**, you can use the `/me/invitable_friends` endpoint in order to render [a custom invite dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.0), then pass the tokens returned by this API to [the standard Requests Dialog.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.0)

In other cases, apps are no longer able to retrieve the full list of a user's friends (only those friends who have specifically authorized your app using the `user_friends` permission). [This has been confirmed by Facebook as 'by design'.](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1502515636638396/)

For apps wanting allow people to invite friends to use an app, you can still use the [Send Dialog on Web](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog) or the new [Message Dialog on iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/message-dialog/) and [Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/message-dialog/).

UPDATE: Facebook have published an FAQ on these changes here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq which explain all the options available to developers in order to invite friends etc.

Comment: Any news since your last edit or we at the same page?

Comment: Can't see the `taggable_friends` in the items for review submission.

Comment: I can not understand why they had to restrict it this much. I mean the old system was way too abusable but this one is next to useless. Seeing the public profile of all your friends would surely not be a privacy issue. Unless you think that the connection of friendship is private itself (but than again why is it not in the case of taggable friends).

This was not a move to restrict privacy abuse that is a side effect, they wanted to close the ability for normal (non facebook affiliated) developers to grow their business using facebook data.

Comment: Facebook has recently published major changes the available data: see [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes/#4-4-2018). The `taggable_friends` now returns nothing. Also, login review is required before you can be granted `user_friends` permission.

Comment: What's the point of providing an API if it does not let you do a basic task such as listing the friends?

Comment: @DuncanJones so there is no way to get my own friends list using the API?

Comment: how this site is getting the facebook friends https://clay.earth

Answer (score 17):

Although *Simon Cross's* answer is accepted and correct, I thought I would beef it up a bit with an example (Android) of what needs to be done. I'll keep it as general as I can and focus on just the question. Personally I wound up storing things in a database so the loading was smooth, but that requires a CursorAdapter and ContentProvider which is a bit out of scope here.

I came here myself and then thought, now what?!

**The Issue**

Just like *user3594351*, I was noticing the friend data was blank. I found this out by using the FriendPickerFragment. What worked three months ago, no longer works. Even Facebook's examples broke. So my issue was 'How Do I create FriendPickerFragment by hand?

**What Did Not Work**

Option #1 from *Simon Cross* was not strong enough to invite friends to the app. *Simon Cross* also recommended the Requests Dialog, but that would only allow five requests at a time. The requests dialog also showed the same friends during any given Facebook logged in session. Not useful.

**What Worked (Summary)**

Option #2 with some hard work. You must make sure you fulfill Facebook's new rules: 1.) You're a game 2.) You have a Canvas app (Web Presence) 3.) Your app is registered with Facebook. It is all done on the Facebook developer website under *Settings*.

To emulate the friend picker by hand inside my app I did the following:

1. Create a tab activity that shows two fragments. Each fragment shows a list. One fragment for available friend (*/me/friends*) and another for invitable friends (*/me/invitable_friends*). Use the same fragment code to render both tabs.
2. Create an AsyncTask that will get the friend data from Facebook. Once that data is loaded, toss it to the adapter which will render the values to the screen.

**Details**

The AsynchTask

```
private class DownloadFacebookFriendsTask extends AsyncTask<FacebookFriend.Type, Boolean, Boolean> {

    private final String TAG = DownloadFacebookFriendsTask.class.getSimpleName();
    GraphObject graphObject;
    ArrayList<FacebookFriend> myList = new ArrayList<FacebookFriend>();

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(FacebookFriend.Type... pickType) {
        //
        // Determine Type
        //
        String facebookRequest;
        if (pickType[0] == FacebookFriend.Type.AVAILABLE) {
            facebookRequest = "/me/friends";
        } else {
            facebookRequest = "/me/invitable_friends";
        }

        //
        // Launch Facebook request and WAIT.
        //
        new Request(
            Session.getActiveSession(),
            facebookRequest,
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                    if (error != null && response != null) {
                        Log.e(TAG, error.toString());
                    } else {
                        graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                    }
                }
            }
        ).executeAndWait();

        //
        // Process Facebook response
        //
        //
        if (graphObject == null) {
            return false;
        }

        int numberOfRecords = 0;
        JSONArray dataArray = (JSONArray) graphObject.getProperty("data");
        if (dataArray.length() > 0) {

            // Ensure the user has at least one friend ...
            for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = dataArray.optJSONObject(i);
                FacebookFriend facebookFriend = new FacebookFriend(jsonObject, pickType[0]);

                if (facebookFriend.isValid()) {
                    numberOfRecords++;

                    myList.add(facebookFriend);
                }
            }
        }

        // Make sure there are records to process
        if (numberOfRecords > 0){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Boolean... booleans) {
        // No need to update this, wait until the whole thread finishes.
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (result) {
            /*
            User the array "myList" to create the adapter which will control showing items in the list.
             */

        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Facebook Thread unable to Get/Parse friend data. Type = " + pickType);
        }
    }
}
```

The FacebookFriend class I created

```
public class FacebookFriend {

    String facebookId;
    String name;
    String pictureUrl;
    boolean invitable;
    boolean available;
    boolean isValid;
    public enum Type {AVAILABLE, INVITABLE};

    public FacebookFriend(JSONObject jsonObject, Type type) {
        //
        //Parse the Facebook Data from the JSON object.
        //
        try {
            if (type == Type.INVITABLE) {
                //parse /me/invitable_friend
                this.facebookId =  jsonObject.getString("id");
                this.name = jsonObject.getString("name");

                // Handle the picture data.
                JSONObject pictureJsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data");
                boolean isSilhouette = pictureJsonObject.getBoolean("is_silhouette");
                if (!isSilhouette) {
                    this.pictureUrl = pictureJsonObject.getString("url");

                } else {
                    this.pictureUrl = "";
                }

                this.invitable = true;
            } else {
                // Parse /me/friends
                this.facebookId =  jsonObject.getString("id");
                this.name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                this.available = true;
                this.pictureUrl = "";
            }

            isValid = true;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.w("#", "Warnings - unable to process Facebook JSON: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about for non-gaming apps? A dating website... a game to find people, an app to find restaurants... a game to find restaurants, etc. you get the idea. So is this REALLY close to games or this is just a way of forcing you to place an app inside Facebook and spending money on their advertisement platform? Who's going to decide what a game is? Who decided that your app is actually a game or not? Don't get me wrong on this but for me it makes no sense to block non-gaming apps unless you just want to force them to use the facebook ecosystem.

Comment: @Mário That is Facebook intention under the hood. You can put anything and mark it as a game as they do not care if it is really a game or not. all they care is getting money from your pocket.

Answer (score 11):

Facebook has revised their policies now. You can’t get the whole friendlist anyway if your app does not have a Canvas implementation and if your app is not a game. Of course there’s also taggable_friends, but that one is for tagging only.

You will be able to pull the list of friends who have authorised the app only.

The apps that are using Graph API 1.0 will be working till April 30th, 2015 and after that it will be deprecated.

See the following to get more details on this:

- *[User Friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends)*
- *[Facebook Application Development FAQ](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app)*

Answer (score 3):

In [Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_%28Apple_programming_language%29) 4.2 and [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) 10.1:

If you want to get the friends list from Facebook, you need to submit your app for review in Facebook. See some of the Login Permissions:

*[Login Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions)*

Here are the two steps:

1) First your **app status is must be in Live**

2) Get **required permissions** form Facebook.

## 1) Enable our app status live:

1. Go to the **apps page** and select **your app**

   https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
2. Select status in the top right in **Dashboard**.

   [image]
3. Submit **privacy policy URL**

   [image]
4. Select **category**

   [image]
5. Now our app is in *Live* status.

   [image]

One step is completed.

## 2) Submit our app for review:

1. First send required requests.

   Example: user_friends, user_videos, user_posts, etc.

   [image]
2. Second, go to the Current Request page

   [image]

   Example: user_events
3. Submit all details

   [image]
4. Like this submit for all requests (user_friends , user_events, user_videos, user_posts, etc.).
5. Finally submit your app for review.

   If your review is accepted from Facebook's side, you are now eligible to read contacts, etc.

Comment: The `user_friends` permission is very limited. From Facebook's documentation (April, 2019):
_[This only] grants an app permission to access a list of friends that also use said app. This permission is restricted to a limited set of partners and usage requires prior approval by Facebook.
In order for a person to show up in another's friend list, both people must have shared their list of friends with the app and not disabled this permission during login._

Comment: What about testers accounts? user_friends is my app, I used a friend's account as a tester, they accepted the request and now their account shows as a tester, but still, not showing when querying the friends?

Answer (score 2):

As Simon mentioned, this is not possible in the new Facebook API. **Pure technically speaking** you can do it via browser automation.

- this is against Facebook policy, so depending on the country where you live, this may not be legal
- you'll have to use your credentials / ask user for credentials and possibly store them (storing passwords even symmetrically encrypted is not a good idea)
- when Facebook changes their API, you'll have to update the browser automation code as well (if you can't force updates of your application, you should put browser automation piece out as a webservice)
- this is bypassing the OAuth concept
- on the other hand, my feeling is that I'm owning my data including the list of my friends and Facebook shouldn't restrict me from accessing those via the API

Sample implementation using [WatiN](http://watin.org/):

```cs
class FacebookUser
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public long Id { get; set; }
}

public IList<FacebookUser> GetFacebookFriends(string email, string password, int? maxTimeoutInMilliseconds)
{
  var users = new List<FacebookUser>();
  Settings.Instance.MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false;
  using (var browser = new IE("https://www.facebook.com"))
  {
    try
    {
      browser.TextField(Find.ByName("email")).Value = email;
      browser.TextField(Find.ByName("pass")).Value = password;
      browser.Form(Find.ById("login_form")).Submit();
      browser.WaitForComplete();
    }
    catch (ElementNotFoundException)
    {
      // We're already logged in
    }
    browser.GoTo("https://www.facebook.com/friends");
    var watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();

    Link previousLastLink = null;
    while (maxTimeoutInMilliseconds.HasValue && watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds < maxTimeoutInMilliseconds.Value)
    {
      var lastLink = browser.Links.Where(l => l.GetAttributeValue("data-hovercard") != null
                       && l.GetAttributeValue("data-hovercard").Contains("user.php")
                       && l.Text != null
                     ).LastOrDefault();

      if (lastLink == null || previousLastLink == lastLink)
      {
        break;
      }

      var ieElement = lastLink.NativeElement as IEElement;
      if (ieElement != null)
      {
        var htmlElement = ieElement.AsHtmlElement;
        htmlElement.scrollIntoView();
        browser.WaitForComplete();
      }

      previousLastLink = lastLink;
    }

    var links = browser.Links.Where(l => l.GetAttributeValue("data-hovercard") != null
      && l.GetAttributeValue("data-hovercard").Contains("user.php")
      && l.Text != null
    ).ToList();

    var idRegex = new Regex("id=(?<id>([0-9]+))");
    foreach (var link in links)
    {
      string hovercard = link.GetAttributeValue("data-hovercard");
      var match = idRegex.Match(hovercard);
      long id = 0;
      if (match.Success)
      {
        id = long.Parse(match.Groups["id"].Value);
      }
      users.Add(new FacebookUser
      {
        Name = link.Text,
        Id = id
      });
    }
  }
  return users;
}
```

Prototype with implementation of this approach (using C#/WatiN) see https://github.com/svejdo1/ShadowApi. It is also allowing dynamic update of Facebook connector that is retrieving a list of your contacts.

Comment: Your code assumes that the app has access to the user's username and password. This isn't how OAuth works, and most users aren't going to provider their FB username and password to an application. That would be a huge security risk.

Comment: This is against Facebook's policy. This advice should not be followed.

Comment: @Ondrej - I agree that this is critical for business, and I am struggling with not having this ability.  That said, this is a horrible answer!!  This is not only against Facebook's policy, it's completely against OAuth.  The whole point of OAuth is to keep a user's password safe while authenticating them.  I'm just planning on pushing users to use Twitter and Google to get at this data.  I am still going to have Facebook OAuth. Overtime, I am hoping that more and more users use my app, the expected functionality will come.

Comment: On another note, you're not even safe guarding your user's credentials in your hack.  Just in case someone decides to use your code, please make sure it uses SSL by changing the uri to https.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar - I wouldn't say this is an evil corporate policy.  Considering the backlash Facebook has received in regards to privacy, I believe this is them listening to their users (the friends who have their information shared without their consent.)  Although it's painful for me, I can understand there logic.  I am sure that another driving factor is the cost associated with buying up all the start-ups that base their infrastructure on Facebook's data.  I do hope that Facebook adds some type of functionality that safe guards the users data, while enabling some type of messaging system.

Comment: "you don't have to care about facebook policies" seriously? :D

Comment: Plus one for shoving it up their face!

Comment: You all sound like Facebook policies are some kind of International Law and by breaking it you are a criminal. Also you think Facebook has only the best for the user in mind, which I think is wrong like @OndrejSvejdar stated, because then they would just let you choose if you want to be seen in other apps. I think this is just a move by Facebook to disrupt the growth of others through their platform FOR FREE. Instead people should start developing their apps, services, games, news etc directly on Facebook. And pay for Facebook advertising when if they won't.

Comment: It might be an idea to grab the data from the mobile site instead: https://m.facebook.com/friends

The mobile version is much simpler and uses less bandwidth.

Comment: Also, you probably won't need a username and password if your friends lists parser is part of a browser extension. The app should work as long as the user's browser is set to a Facebook page.

Comment: @jbustamovej if someone wants to backup their friends list without entering their credentials in a third-party app, I made a script that can be used in a web browser: https://gist.github.com/baptx/1525f338d93fa01db4e0

Answer (score 2):

Try `/me/taggable_friends?limit=5000` using your JavaScript code

Or

try the [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API):

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/user_id_here/taggable_friends?access_token=

Comment: As I think - downvotes here are because "Use of this endpoint requires review by Facebook and should only be used for the case where you're rendering a list of friends in order to let the user tag them in a post." You can read more about this in selected answer.

Comment: {
   "data": [
      
   ],
   "summary": {
      "total_count": 414
   }
}
i got this json data block null not get friends.
What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are still struggling with this issue on a development mode.
Follow the same process as mentioned below:

1. create a test app of your main app,
2. create test users, automatically install app for test users and assign them 'user_friend' permission.
3. Add your test users as a friend with each other.

I followed the same process after going through alot of research and finally it worked.[image]

Answer (score -1):

In the Facebook SDK Graph API v2.0 or above, you must request the *user_friends* permission from each user in the time of Facebook login since *user_friends* is no longer included by default in every login; we have to add that.

Each user must grant the *user_friends* permission in order to appear in the response to */me/friends*.

```
let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.web
fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email","user_friends","public_profile"], from: self) { (result, error) in
    if (error == nil) {

        let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result!
        if fbloginresult.grantedPermissions != nil {
            if (fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email")) {
                // Do the stuff
            }
            else {
            }
        }
        else {
        }
    }
}
```

So at the time of Facebook login, it prompts with a  screen which contain all the permissions:

[image]

If the user presses the *Continue* button, the permissions will be set. When you access the friends list using Graph API, your friends who logged into the application as above will be listed

```
if ((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil) {
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me/friends", parameters: ["fields" : "id,name"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {

            print(result!)
        }
    })
}
```

The output will contain the users who granted the *user_friends* permission at the time of login to your application through Facebook.

```
{
    data = (
             {
                 id = xxxxxxxxxx;
                 name = "xxxxxxxx";
             }
           );
    paging = {
        cursors = {
            after = xxxxxx;
            before = xxxxxxx;
        };
    };
    summary = {
        "total_count" = 8;
    };
}
```